# Spring JPA mongodb using annotations

Tags: spring, mongodb, annotations, persistence

Help me understand this. I am using spring-data-mongodb without hibernate or any other jpa provider. My domain model is like this:

```
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  ...
}
```

I run a test class to populate a few users in my mongodb, which works fine. But if I add a few more annotations like this:

```
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;
  @Field(value="uname") private String username;
  @Field(value="pass")private String password;
  ...
}
```

my test class adds just one user, the next one throws exception complaining of duplicate entries -

> org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error index: gldata.user.$username_-1  dup key: { : null }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error index: gldata.user.$username_-1  dup key: { : null }

What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess here is that in the second case, Spring-JPA is not able to auto-generate ids, the first id (object id in mongo) is generated using null, the second id then becomes a duplicate. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find out why this was happening, I found a workaround. Using ObjectId instead of String for id field, works very well.